# MarkLogic Java API overwrite jersey RuntimeDelegate

Tags: java, marklogic, jersey-client

When using MarkLogic Java API, Any other piece of code that try to use jersey client will load MockRuntimeDelegate class of MarkLogic package which cause NPE.

the ML pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>marklogic-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

jersey client use (Scala code):

```
val webResource: WebResource = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig(classOf[MultiPartWriter])).resource(ROOT_URL)
```

The exception:

```
←[31m  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:←[0m
←[31m  at 
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBod
←[31m  at 
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBod
←[31m  at 
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactor
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)←[0m
←[31m  at 
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:171)←[0m
←[31m  ...←[0m
←[31m  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException:←[0m
←[31m  at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:196)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.<clinit>
(MediaTypes.java:65)←[0m
←[31m  at 
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBod
←[31m  at 
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBod
←[31m  at 
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactor
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)←[0m
←[31m  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)←[0m
←[31m  at 
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)←[0m
```

This exception is because MarkLogic implementation in MockRuntimeDelegate return null for any use of `createHeaderDelegate()`.

Since this class is in the class path - any other try of use simple jersey client will cause this error.

The reason is that jersey code is using the class loader to find any implementation of RuntimeDelegate and MarkLogic is the first in the class path (before the right impl of RuntimeDelegateImpl jersey package class)

The only solution I found is to set explicitly the RuntimeDelegete class before the client code:

```
RuntimeDelegate.setInstance(new RuntimeDelegateImpl)
```

Is there more elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the right way for now. I have created a task in Marklogic Java Client API for removing the mock implementation of RuntimeDelegate. You can track the progress here - https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/892

Comment: Thanks. 
Btw, design speaking, I would say that jersey did it wrong also...